# Two text boxes aligned to the bottom, the second one can grow up and push the first div up

Tags: html, css

I have two text boxes that must be aligned to the bottom of a parent div. The second div can change his height growing up and then It is going to push the first div up.

My two problems are:

- Align both div to the bottom
- Push the first div up when the second div grows

Explanation Img:

[image]

```
.parent{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
.div1{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.div2-helper{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.div2{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: post ur full code with html

Comment: try to make a last effort to provide us a working (or even not) chunk of html code, that you've got already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `div`s inside a container and use `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`

I have created a working example for you. Click on the button to increase height of the lower div and check for yourself.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(".second-div").height(parseInt($(".second-div").height(), 10) + 10);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.btn {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.first-div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.second-div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="btn">Click to increase height
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first-div">

    </div>
    <div class="second-div">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this situation I can't use JavaScript only HTML5+CSS3, thank you for the response anyway

Comment: @Danychi The javascript has been used to show you that on change of height of `second-div` it auto adjusts. Its for demo purposes. You don't need it. Just use the html structure & css.

Comment: I tried it now, It works perfectly, I used height auto for the second div.
Thank you for the response @nashcheez

Don't know why I had a negative vote though.

Comment: @Danychi Because you did not have a working example of your code. People at SO can be very objective & ruthless.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind for the future, thank you again :)